# Laravel - How to get data like hasOne in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Here are my tables having a many-to-many relationship and group_user as the intermediate table.

```
| users     | groups      | group_user    |
-------------------------------------------
| id        | id          | group_id      |
| name      | name        | user_id       |
| created_at| creator_id  | created_at    |
| updated_at| created_at  | updated_at    |
|           | updated_at  |               |
```

groups.creator is the user id referenced from users table.

When I try to query the group table, it returns something like this.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Akatsuki","creator":1,"created_at":"2015-10-13 12:22:20","updated_at":"2015-10-13 12:22:20"}]
```

What I want is when I query the groups table, it also returns the user data of the creator like hasOne relationships do.

In User Model

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In Group Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Check this documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many  .   Check this laracast video too https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21 . I think it will help you

Comment: Not quite clear as what you want, can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I query the groups, I just overwrite the group_creator column.

```
foreach($available as $data) {
    $data['group_creator'] = User::find($data['group_creator']);
}
```

Now it returns

```
[{"id":1,"group_name":"Akatsuki","creator":{"id":1,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","created_at":"2015-10-13 12:19:35","updated_at":"2015-10-13 14:14:41"},"created_at":"2015-10-13 12:22:20","updated_at":"2015-10-13 12:22:20"}]
```

Along with the user details.